# VR PvP game with space-like physics

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I played a VR game 1-2 years ago, and want to figure out which one it was because it was an interesting game. I played it at a 'VR game lobby', I guess you could call it. I didn't own the VR set, I went to a store and rented it for an hour or two and played there.

The console;

Not trying to go into super detail about the console but it should help narrow it down some. It had a tether going up to the ceiling, and a single camera to track movement on the back wall(so not one of the newer oculus ones). It wasn't a 'stick a phone in with a pre-downloaded app and then play' console. It had the visor dealio which had the tether, and two hand controllers. I think the left one(but it may have been the right one) had some tubes or something shaped kinda like a basket coming from the top of the controller. Not sure why though. I don't think, but may be wrong, that the controllers had hoops in the front like some VR controllers. The controllers had a joystick, a home and menu button on the top. On the side and in front were a trigger and grip button. I also remember that the grip button was kinda annoying to keep pressed but the controllers were probably just sized for someone with bigger hands.

After getting back, I remember googling the set, but it costed over $300, so I didn't research much beyond that. I also remember you could use more cameras to get a larger area where you can move around.

Talked to my dad who was with me and was a bit more interested in the console, he thinks it was an oculus rift s, but that doesn't require any cameras although they may be there to make the play area bigger. Might not be the right console though but that's what he thinks it was.

The game;
It was pretty simple but fun, you had a movement thingy on your left hand that you used to move. You pointed it the way you wanted to go and pushed the trigger, and you went that way. You could also switch it out for guns if you wanted to. The right hand started with a gun, I mostly used a grenade launcher thing. You pulled the trigger button to shoot, and to detonate the grenade you pulled the trigger again. I feel like it was called the pineapple or some kind of fruit, but it might had been a different gun. I'm also pretty sure there was a machine gun type weapon.

The skins of the players kinda looked like those guys from Halo with the big armor suits(I've never played but I think they're called spartans) but less bulky. There was also no gravity in the game world, you moved just by your left hand movement thingy. There was friction, so if you stopped pulling the trigger to move you drifted to a stop pretty quickly. The map I played in had some houses floating around, some had porches and pillars and stuff but seemed to be two stories tall. The entire world was in a sphere of hexagons, kinda like that [giant golf ball at Epcot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_Earth_(Epcot)). Other players could join from other places and you could chat with the other players as well.

Comment: @Valorum, The florr wasn't hexes, the sphere surroudning the game world was

Comment: So did you stand or sit when playing? You mentioned that movement was with the joystick, but did turning your body physically, ducking, or walking change your location as well?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, you moved with the left trigger button by pointing, but I played standing and you can turn and move around in the little box and it would transfer into the virtual world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Skyfront VR*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/640800/Skyfront_VR/).

You play inside a variety of low and zero gravity arenas. You have a grenade launcher called the "pineapple launcher". Most of the arenas are bounded by a geodesic dome made of what looks like swirly glass.

Comment: yes i think this is it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Vertigo*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/465430/Vertigo/) (2016)?

You can see the geodesic dome in this clip

Comment: Presumably you were playing on some version of the [Vive](https://www.theverge.com/2016/4/5/11358618/htc-vive-vr-review) if this is the correct game.

Comment: No not this, sorry. good suggestion though.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b - You surprise me.